# Server memory (htop)

Tags: linux, memory

Can anyone explain what the colors in the memory section represent? Is this server healthy, or does it need more RAM?

[image]

[l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ9v7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>F1</kbd> for help and htop will show you a legend which explains each color.

[image: htop help]

Comment: Thanks. Is it ok to reach the max with cached? Meaning, should i be concerned that the used+cached has maxed out?

Comment: @danielb https://www.linuxatemyram.com/